# trying to create a general rule for concatenating files with make

Tags: makefile

I have two folders that look something like this:

```
process:

raw:
a_1.x.txt   a_2.x.txt   b_1.x.txt   b_2.x.txt
a_1.x.dat   a_2.x.dat   b_1.x.dat   b_2.x.dat
```

These txt files are dumps from binary files `*.dat` that will be created by another rule. I would like to create a make file that will pool the `raw/%_#.txt` files to create `process/%.txt`. I can do this with...

```
process/a.txt : raw/a_1.x.txt raw/a_2.x.txt
    cat $^ > $@

process/b.txt : raw/b_1.x.txt raw/b_2.x.txt
    cat $^ > $@
```

... when I do `make process/a.txt` or `make process/b.txt`. But in my real life problem, I have a, b, c, etc and each has a variable number of files in the raw folder. So, I'd like to create a general rule to do this for me.

I've tried...

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
process/%.txt : $$(join $$(join raw/,%),$$(wildcard *.x.txt)))
    cat $^ > $@
```

But the make command comes back with

`make: *** No rule to make target 'process/a.txt'.  Stop.`

Ditto for:

```
process/%.txt : $$(patsubst raw,process,$$(patsubst .txt, $$(wildcard *.x.txt),))
    cat $^ > $@`
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can be of help:

```
DATA = $(wildcard raw/*.dat)
TEXTS = $(patsubst %.dat,%.txt,$(DATA))
PROCESSED = $(subst raw,process,$(TEXTS))


all: $(PROCESSED)


%.txt: %.dat
    touch $@

process/%.txt: raw/%.txt
    touch $@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using this quite extensively now :)